# a2ensite error "Site not exist" when creating virtualhost apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04

I have created files for my site in the /home/junda/www/ directory. I use symfony2, means the public files goes to /home/junda/www/symfony2-tries/web/ directory.

I then type this following command to the terminal to change permission:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX ~/www
sudo chmod a+rx ~
```

I also create /etc/apache2/sites-available/symfony2-tries.com file with following content:

```
# domain: symfony2-tries.com
# public: /home/junda/www/symfony2-tries.com/

<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@symfony2-tries.com
  ServerName  www.symfony2-tries.com
  ServerAlias symfony2-tries.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex app.php
  DocumentRoot /home/junda/www/symfony2-tries/web


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/junda/www/symfony2-tries/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/junda/www/symfony2-tries/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

after that i tried to enable it using a2ensite.

```
sudo a2ensite symfony2-tries
```

but it returns:

```
ERROR: Site symfony2-tries.com does not exist!
```

Could anyone kindly told me where I did wrong? And if possible, how to correct it.
Thank You very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found the solution!

All files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` must have the `.conf` extension now.

Example: `symfony2-tries` rename it in `symfony2-tries.conf`

Type `sudo a2ensite symfony2-tries.conf` and restart apache.